# Electron 6 - context menus now use the OS's theme (dark or light) by default. How to override this behavior?

Tags: electron

After migrating from Electron 5 to 6, I noticed that context menus now automatically use the OS's theme (I'm using Windows 10).

If you set the Windows 10 theme color to "dark", context menus will now be dark. The same thing applies if you are using the "light" theme, context menus will be light.

I've looked through Electron's docs and release notes but I couldn't find how to override this behavior.

Is it possible to set the color of context menus regardless of the OS's theme?

## **Screenshots**

**Electron 5.0.6** context menu (Windows 10 theme is dark but Electron is not theme aware)

[image]

**Electron 6.1.3** context menu (Windows 10 theme is dark) [Also the text is truncated for some reason]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no way of testing it, but in the most recent `Electron 7.1.0`, [nativeTheme.themeSource](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-theme#nativethemethemesource) may be what you're looking for:

> A String property that can be **system**, **light** or **dark**. It is used to
>   override and supercede the value that Chromium has chosen to use
>   internally.
>
> Setting this property to **system** will remove the override and
>   everything will be reset to the OS default. By default themeSource is
>   **system**.
>
> [...]
>
> Settings this property to **light** will have the following effects:
>
> - nativeTheme.shouldUseDarkColors will be false when accessed
> - Any UI Electron renders on Linux and Windows including **context menus**, devtools, etc. will use the light UI.
> - Any UI the OS renders on macOS including menus, window frames, etc. will use the light UI.
> - The prefers-color-scheme CSS query will match light mode.
> - The updated event will be emitted

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed what I was looking for, but it's not ideal. This API is introduced in Electron 7+ not 6. That being said, I can verify that it works on 7 because I've tested it.